# How to add defer attribute to all enqued stylesheet in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

the optimization plugins create a combined css like this `wp-content/cache/jch-optimize/css/44f36652432a64a9ac3046e69e02f4a5.css` and how can i add defer tag to this style which is being changed every time via function.php?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a Cache plugin to handle CSS.

You could try [this](https://matthewhorne.me/defer-async-wordpress-scripts/) (hook on `script_loader_tag`) to see if you can edit the `<script>` output to add your attribute.

But if a cache plugin handles itself the "enqueuing" of the cached assets, you may need to look its documentation to see if it's possible.